# How to transform inner Node structure in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have ben trying to solve this transformation problem for a while.

```
<ParentNode>
    <RequirementGroup>
        <ID>id1</ID>
        <Requirement>
            <ID>id2</ID>
            <Description>value1</Description>
        </Requirement>
        <RequirementGroup pi="attribute">
            <ID>id3</ID>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id4</ID>
                <Description>value2</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id5</ID>
                <Description>value3</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id6</ID>
                <Description>value4</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id7</ID>
                <Description>value5</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <RequirementGroup>
                <ID>id8</ID>
                <Requirement>
                    <ID>id9</ID>
                    <Description>value6</Description>
                </Requirement>
                <RequirementGroup pi="attribute">
                    <ID>id10</ID>
                    <Requirement>
                        <ID>id11</ID>
                        <Description>value7</Description>
                    </Requirement>
                </RequirementGroup>
            </RequirementGroup>
        </RequirementGroup>
        <RequirementGroup>
            <ID>id12</ID>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id13</ID>
                <Description>value8</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <RequirementGroup pi="attribute">
                <ID>id14</ID>
                <Requirement>
                    <ID>id15</ID>
                    <Description>value9</Description>
                </Requirement>
                <Requirement>
                    <ID>id16</ID>
                    <Description>value10</Description>
                </Requirement>
                <Requirement>
                    <ID>id17</ID>
                    <Description>value11</Description>
                </Requirement>
            </RequirementGroup>
        </RequirementGroup>
    </RequirementGroup>
</ParentNode>
```

Regarding to this XML structure, I want to copy the same structure with other node names and also copying the values into new node names.

As you can see the `<RequirementGroup>` node has another same node with the same attribute inside. I can reach the first one , but not the inner one with loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="RequirementGroup">
    <NewNode1>
        <xsl:if test="RequirementGroup">
            <xsl:call-template name="sometemplate" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="Requirement">
            <NewNode2>
                <xsl:call-template name="template" />
            </NewNode2>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="RequirementGroup[@pi='attribute']">
            <xsl:for-each select="RequirementGroup[@pi='attribute']">
                <NewNode3>
                    <xsl:call-template name="anothertemplate" />
                    <xsl:if test="Requirement">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Requirement">
                            <NewNode2>
                                <xsl:call-template name="othertemplate" />
                            </NewNode2>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if>
                </NewNode3>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </NewNode1>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So with this logic I have the same structure, but only one of the `<RequirementGroup>` with `pi` attribute is returned. Not the others which is inside it. Sorry for the bad explanation, hope i managed to tell the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to copy the input to the output,
changing only element names, e.g. `RequirementGroup` to `NewNode1`.

So, to perform the above change (for a single element name), you need the
following template:

```
<xsl:template match="RequirementGroup">
  <NewNode1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </NewNode1>
</xsl:template>
```

For each other element, which name is to be changed, you need analogous
template, replacing `match` criterion and the name of the created element.

Another solution is to create a "composite" template for a few element names,
e.g. for names `source_1`, `source_2` and `source_3` to be changed to
`target_1`, `target_2` and `target_3`, create something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="source_1 | source_2 | source_3">
  <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="
    if (name() = 'source_1') then 'target_1'
    else if (name() = 'source_2') then 'target_2'
    else 'target_3'"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, in both cases your script must include also the *identity template*.

### Edit

Yet another solution - **one** "universal" template (below), including:

- A list of source and target names (of equal length).
- `ind` variable - position of the name of the current element on the source list
  (in not found - empty).
- `tagName` variable - target element name from the *target* list or the original name
  (if not found).

The rest as in previous solution.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="srcNames" select="('source_1','source_2','source_3')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="trgNames" select="('target_1','target_2','target_3')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ind" select="index-of($srcNames, name())[1]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="
    if ($ind) then $trgNames[$ind] else name()"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the solution i want, imagine that this structure is repeating itself many times up to total 4000 lines. i want to know how to nest the inner structure, applicable to my solution as i shared in the question. I want to know where is the mistake in my logic ? only the second level of RequirementGroup with pi attribute i cant recurse. Others are fine.